# How I can reach records by knowing foreign key?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity user and another entity comment. Entity comment has foreign key: `user_id` is integer which is primary key in entity user, entity user also has column name. I use this:

```
 $comments = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Comment')->findAll();
```

to get all comments, then I use `'comments' => $comments,` to sent data to the twig, then in the twig:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    {{ comment.id }}
    {{ comment.comment }}
{% endfor %}
```

`comment.id` will write `user_id`, but I want instead of `user_id` I would get user name. How can i do that?

Comment: What do your Comment and User entities look like (code I mean)? @adashbob 's point is correct, you can do the mapping, but it needs to be more than just what he's shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have correctly define the relationship in the `Comment` entity like exmple :

```
/**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="YourBundle\Entity\User")
  */
 private $user;
```

Then you can get the name of user by :

```
{{ comment.user.name }}
```

Comment: ManyToOne would be a better mapping relation in this case. I don't think a user can make only one comment